# Vista glass effect in Silverlight 2.0

Tags: silverlight, .net-3.5

I want to create a panel in Silverlight 2.0 with the same properties and look as the Vista glass region that you get as a window border.

I am especially interested in the blur and the frost effects.

Comment: Here is the article that explains about getting glass effect in Silverlight. http://codingforpassion.blogspot.com/2011/08/glass-effect-silverlight-charts.html

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of this:

http://michaelsync.net/2008/11/08/silverlight-glass-button

[image]
<sub>(source: [michaelsync.net](http://michaelsync.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/silverlight-glass-button.jpg))</sub>

This example doesn't include a Blur effect, but we wont have that built in to Silverlight until v3 comes out. I think Silverlight 3 is supposed to be released by the end of July.

Anyway here's a link that shows how to use the Silverlight 3 Blur Effect:
http://www.silverlightshow.net/tips/Using-Blur-and-DropShadow-effects-in-Silverlight-3.aspx

Comment: You may have to wait for Silverlight 3 to do a Blur. Silverlight 3 has a Blur Effect built in.